# Problem with connecting to SQL Server in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, database-connection

I've created an ASP.NET Core MVC application and I have tested it with SQL server 2016 on my laptop and every thing works fine. After publishing the project and moving published files on server, the page does not appear. On the server SQL server 2014 is installed. The error on IIS says:

> The page could not load resources.

My connection string is:

```
"Server=server IP;Database=Archive;User Id=sa;Password=123;Integrated Security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Trust server certificate=True;"
```

Is this problem because of difference between SQL server versions?
Any suggestion will be appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: I have two idea .please test way #1 
.If you do not succeed, try the second method

1.first change type  Persist Security Info to True("Persist Security Info=True")
 
2.you can test connection use udl and use new connection string in copy with current https://industrial-software.com/training-support/tech-notes/tn124/

Comment: The `Persist Security Info` connection property doesn't affect the ability to connect, it determines whether or not security material can be obtained from the `SqlConnection` instance by the application (or logging services) at runtime. The default and strongly recommended setting is False/No.

Comment: I assume you're seeing the error message in your web browser console tab, `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of` (for example) `503 (Service Unavailable)`. Do you have remote access to the web server? Are you able to open the Event Viewer to see what error information IIS is reporting there? How you previously had this web application connecting to the SQL Server or is this a new feature? Does the web server actually have network access to the SQL Server instance (via network firewalls and software firewalls)?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning
Thanks for making comment on my question. As you mentioned, i get the exact error you just mentioned and i have remote access to server and i can connect to database through access without any problem. I get the error on server when try to display page. On client system there is not any error.